# Unusual javascript HTTP caching / undefined issues

Tags: javascript, caching, undefined, intermittent

Ok. I have never seen anything like this before and I am quite confused... On a website I am working on, there are two JavaScript includes. (Well, many more, but the problem occurs with only two). We'll call these `A.js` and `B.js`.

`A.js` defines a JavaScript singleton `A`. Likewise `B.js` defines a JavaScript singleton `B`. The `B` class depends on methods from `A`.

I have almost all my code wrapped up in `try { ... } catch { ... }` blocks, and on error, the system generates an AJAX request to email me the details of the error.

On one system here in my office (Firefox 3.0 for Mac) I am seeing the strangest behavior. Once in a while, maybe once every hour or two, but with no specific pattern, I get an error email from class `B`: `"ReferenceError: A is undefined."`

I have no idea why/how `A` would be undefined *sometimes*. When I look in the apache logs, during the times I receive the error, the client is requesting `/A.js`, before requesting `/B.js`, and the server is responding with a `304` (Not Modified)

I somehow suspect the issue is that the file has expired from the client cache however the server doesnt send the file thus it is never executed and `A` is undefined. But that's just a guess and I don't understand why that would happen. And if I am guessing right, how do I fix it???

If it matters, `mod_disk_cache` was enabled on the server, and I have disabled it to see if that was causing the problem. If so, maybe this belongs on ServerFault...

Any suggestions very welcome!!

Comment: Too vague. Post the actual source code that loads the scripts, and also specify if you're using any other frameworks, and, if so, how you're loading them.

Comment: @Jonathan Feinberg: I understand it's a vague question. But each script is thousands of lines long and yes, I am using a custom built framework which is many thousands of lines long. I'll gladly post source code, just need to know where to start...

Comment: How are you including the .js files?  e.g. inline <script> tags or loading them dynamically on page load/first use?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Webdevelopers toolbar installed in Firefox, activate "Disable Cache" it helps a lot on debugging.

Comment: That's a good idea. I will try that and see if the results change. Actually, the computer this is happening on does not have that toolbar but I can disable cache in `about:config`

Answer (score 0):

start calling the first js function **after**! the page has loaded, do this by `<body onload="startmyfunction()">` or similar.

Comment: Yes, I already do that. If I open Firebug on the affected computer and eval: `A`, it is undefined. So something else is at play here.